# Is it a bad idea to bundle multiple API endpoints into a single aggregate endpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-design

Say I'm building an application about food. I have endpoints for food images, food nutritional data, and food ratings.

In my mobile application, I call all three of these endpoints when a user searches for a food.

In addition to having the three endpoints separated like this, would it be a bad idea to have a single endpoint that returns the same data but in just one request?

Could this theoretically save time and resources?

Answer (score 1):

> would it be a bad idea to have a single endpoint that returns the same data but in just one request?

Ofcourse not! When a user hits an api for lets say `show` action, the server should respond with all the necessary and relevant data required for the client to render it in one request.

> Could this theoretically save time and resources

Theoretically and practically both,

- firstly, user data is saved when hitting single request instead of 3/more..
- 3 requests will increase the latency, response time by 3x where it is not necessary, it affects both ui and ux.
- 3 requests will mostly spawn 3 queries to db where in most cases if you have associated model, data can be fetched using 1

These are only few i can list down, there are many pros of it.